# NOTEPAD++ Regex How delete all characters between a substring and ,

Tags: regex, notepad++

I haven't used Regular Expressions before and now I find myself needed to make a series of alterations to a file...really quick.

Basically I have the following SQL:

```
VALUES(N'Some string here', etc...
```

I need to get rid of the first parameter in the VALUES statement N'Some string here'

How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'll take the downvote hit, I needed this answer ultra quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a substitution from:

```
VALUES\(N'[^']*',\s
```

to

```
VALUES(
```

Use `N?` (instead of `N`) if you **optionally** have `N` before the string.

Comment: Thanks! That worked except VALUES( was just replaced with VALUES so I had to then add back the ( with a replace. Its time I really learned regular expressions, I don't know why I haven't yet. So damn powerful.

Comment: In the substitution entry you don't have to escape `(`. I don't know which versione of Notepad++ you use, but I tried **my** substitution with **v.5.9.3** and it correctly replaces with `VALUES(`.